# How do I fill in data into a 2D array, with 2 lines of input in c++?

Tags: c++, input, io, user-input

Input (2 lines):

```
3
1234 1234 1234.
```

The first line is the number of numbers I'm going to input, and the second line is the numbers themselves (all 4 digits). I want to store the input data in a 2D array (int a[3][4]). How can I do this? If I use a nested for loop, the input won't be in this format

Comment: I believe you can take the second input as a string and then parse it (split it by spaces and then convert each element to a number).

Comment: Are you sure that you need a 2d array? A 1d array `int[3]` would be sufficient to store the input as well. Btw. if the number is something which is not known at compile time (as it looks like) I would go with a dynamic array - `std::vector<int>` in this case.

Comment: We're not going to do your work for you. Try it first and then tell us where you get stuck.